# Why does my Docker MySQL lose privileges for some users?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am using the mysql 8 image in a docker compose file. Periodically I discover that the mysql user I set up for a database no longer has privileges on that database. The user still exists and has `GRANT USAGE on *.*` but all the database specific privileges are gone. I use this same user on multiple databases in this container. Is there something about my configuration that's causing mysql to lose that information? Or is it default and I need to do something to prevent it?

The relevant part of my docker-compose.yml file

```
  aspodb:
    container_name: aspodb
    image: mysql:8
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    command: mysqld --max_allowed_packet=256M
    networks:
      - asponet
    volumes:
      - aspodata:/var/lib/mysql
      - aspodatatmp:/var/tmp
      - ./setup/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./setup/mysqlcnf/aspodb.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/aspodb.cnf
```